# C# accessing active directory with different user credentials

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

There is a new user creation application that we have just provided our users. However these users need the ability to creation users through the application even though they themselves do not have permission to create users.

In C# how do you impersonate another user in order to have this functionality. This application primary using `System.DirectoryServices`.

Code snippet:

```
DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=");
DirectorySearcher dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);
//filter just user objects
dSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(mail=" + excel_Holding_Table.Rows[i]["EmailAddress"].ToString() + "))";
dSearcher.PageSize = 1000;
sResults = dSearcher.FindAll();
```

Comment: Run the process/service as administrator? I know how to do that manually, but I don't know how it would work in .NET on an automatic basis.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`DirectoryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) class directly and specify the username and password:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path);

de.Username = "username";
de.Password = "password";
```

And access Active Directory from the de object.  Or you can use the `WindowsIdentity` class and and impersonate a User:

```
WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
```

A full code sample is available at:

[Impersonation and DirectoryEntry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957886/impersonation-and-directoryentry)

Answer (score 0):

Use [the `DirectoryEntry` constructor that takes username, password and authenticationType parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2h7eed.aspx).

As an aside, the `DirectoryEntry` `DirectorySearcher` and `SearchResultCollection` types are `IDisposable` - you need to dispose them, probably with `using` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DirectoryEntry Constructor (String, String, String, AuthenticationTypes) that takes a username and password instead of impersonation.

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + serverName + "/W3SVC/1/Root", @"domain\username", "password", AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.Sealing);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620566/impersonate-not-working-for-directoryservices)

Answer (score 0):

You can use privileged credentials to connect to AD or to impersonate a privileged user as other answers have suggested.

But this has security implications, since it means your users would be able to use these privileged credentials for other, non-authorized, purposes.

A more secure solution would be to create a web service that runs under a service account with appropriate AD permissions.  Users can authenticate to the web service using Windows authentication, and the web service would create users on their behalf.  It could use authorization to restrict what users are allowed to do (e.g. only create users in their own department).